# Get element by data attribute using label and add disabled class

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code here i want to disable the selective checkbox using get element by data attribute which is that "data-wapf-label" which I had in my webpage once my web page loads so i applied the disabled class but did not worked

```js
$('.wapf-input[data-wapf-label="haribo strawberry"]').addClass('disabled');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Strawberry</span></span>
</div>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span> Strawberr1</span></span>
</div>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Haribo11</span></span>
</div>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Haribo111</span></span>
</div>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Haribo12</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just an error on your selector:

1. the string in `data-wapf-label` is cas sensitive, so adapt like in your html.

   ```
    $('input[data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry"]').addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
   ```

if you add `i`  you'll have case insensitive:

```
    $('input[data-wapf-label="haribo strawberry" i]').addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
```

```js
$('input[data-wapf-label="haribo strawberry" i]').prop('disabled', true).
parent().closest('div').addClass("disabled");

$('div').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Strawberry</span></span>
</div>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span> Strawberr1</span></span>
</div>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Haribo11</span></span>
</div>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Haribo111</span></span>
</div>
<div class="wapf-swatch wapf-swatch--image wapf-checked">
  <input type="hidden" class="wapf-tf-h" data-fid="5fd25d21855fd" value="0" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wapf[field_5fd25d21855fd][]" class="wapf-input" data-field-id="5fd25d21855fd" value="kd4ik" data-wapf-label="Haribo Strawberry" data-is-required="" data-maxc="">
  <span class="wapf-ttp"><span>Haribo12</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: no its working you have the class disabled added for the selection desired if you check the html in debbuger of the browser.

Comment: sir you can check it here.. i check it the variation checkbox is stick clicable take a look[link]http://sweetshop.nantwichwebdesign.co.uk/product/1kg-pouch/

Comment: if you want to disabled checkbox, i suppose you have an action when you add disabled in class..?

Comment: yeah this is what i want just disabled that checkbox which has that label name whicver i wants simple

Comment: if you want to disable you have to add attribute or property following the version of jquery disabled to true see my answer modifed

Comment: you almost there.. but not the checkbox is disabled but the class "disabled " not added you can run it in codesnippet

Comment: in my snippet all is functional, the class disabled is added in input  tag and the checkbox is disabled

Comment: yeah sir but i want to add the disabled to this div "wapf-swatch" you can check the div please

Comment: i cant guess, you didnt ask that

Comment: we almost there but this div need to be disabled by prop the disabled class using same condition

Comment: div has the class disabled now

Comment: you awesome it saves my day sir.. great

Answer (score -1):

```
let $selector = $('.wapf-swatch');
let $item = '.wapf-input';
$selector.each(function() {
    $(this).find($item).attr("data-wapf-label","haribo strawberry").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: Please consider adding text that explains your answer. The site is a Q/A site where questions and answers are posted with the goal of helping future visitors with similar problems. Your answer might help the OP, but without explanatory text that is separate from code, it won't help those future visitors.

Comment: not working you can check here [link]http://sweetshop.nantwichwebdesign.co.uk/product/1kg-pouch/

Comment: Please check now it will work, I updated the code.